# "jaxDecomp installation error" Run setup.py，command execution error #3

Tags: python, hpc, jax

error message：

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
By not providing "FindNVHPC.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "NVHPC", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "NVHPC" with any of
the following names:

NVHPCConfig.cmake
nvhpc-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "NVHPC" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"NVHPC_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "NVHPC"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

provide FindNVHPC.cmake or NVHPCConfig.cmake/nvhpc-config.cmake

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this problem by reinstall the nvidia hpc sdk, attend to select the single cuda version (not nvhpc_..._cuda_multi.tar.gz)